# Function to read data from a file into heap memory

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I am writing a function that reads the number of grades in a text file and stores them into heap memory. It writes the count to location pointed to by ptr_cnt and returns the address of the first byte stored into said heap memory.

I have written this and the count works just fine. However the data does not seem to be getting written into the the heap. When I print out the first heap, I get 0.000.

```
double *read_data(char const *file_name, int *ptr_cnt)
{
    FILE *read = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (read == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(read)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    *ptr_cnt = count;

    double *heap;
    heap = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * count);
    double num = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; fscanf(read, "%lf", &num) != EOF; i++)
    {
        *(heap + i) = num;
    }
    fclose(read);
    return heap;
    free(heap);
}
```

Comment: Your first loop already consumes the file stream until the end, so the second loop will not iterate. Did you actually use a debugger? It would show immediately and save you a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. `malloc` returns a `void*`,  which can implicitly be converted to any object pointer type. In general, casts are evil and conceal more serious errors in your code.

Comment: Also, that `free(heap)` at the end does nothing; it's dead code since the return statement just prior makes the function stop.

Comment: I've added a rewind(read) after the first loop and the code words fine now. Thanks for the replies.